# Convergence a.e. of a sequence of random variables (an equivalence is to show)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, proof-verification

> > Show: For a sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of random variables it is:
> >     $$
> > (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ converges a.e.}\Leftrightarrow\forall~\varepsilon>0:~\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j,k\geq n}\left\{\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right)=0
> > $$

Hello, concerning "$\Rightarrow$" here is my previous idea:

It is for any $\varepsilon > 0$
$$
\bigcup_{j,k\geq n}\left\{\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert > \varepsilon\right\}\subset \left\{\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\},
$$
so it follows
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{j,k\geq n}\left\{\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert > \varepsilon\right\})\leq\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right).
$$
Moreover, it is
$$
\left\{\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\supseteq \left\{\sup_{j,k\geq n+1}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\},~~~~~\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right)<\infty
$$
so that I can apply the $\sigma$-continuity of $\mathbb{P}$, getting
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right)\to \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right).
$$
I am not totally sure, but I think that
$$
\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\subset\left\{\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\text{ for infinite many }(j,k)\right\}\\\subset\left\{\omega\in\Omega: (X_n)\mbox{ does not converge }\right\}~~~(*),
$$
what means that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{j,k\geq n}\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right)\leq\mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: (X_n)\mbox{ does not converge }\right\})=0.
$$
Put all together I get
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{j,k\geq n}\left\{\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert > \varepsilon\right\})\to 0.
$$

As I said, I am not totally clear about the first inclusion of $(*)$.

Is that inclusion right? Is that proof right?

What about "$\Leftarrow$"? Can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the underlying probability space be $\Omega$ and $\{ \epsilon_n\}$ a strictly positive sequence that goes to $0$. Then

$$
\{ \omega  \in \Omega: X_n \; \mbox{does not converge at}\; \omega\}
$$

$$
= \bigcup_{\epsilon_n}  \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{j,k \geq n}  \{ \lvert X_j-X_k \rvert >\epsilon_n \}. 
$$

So

$$
\mathbb{P} \left( \{ \omega  \in \Omega: X_n \; \mbox{does not converge at}\; \omega\} \right) = 0
$$

if and only if, for every $\epsilon_n$,

$$
 \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{j,k \geq n}  \{ \lvert X_j-X_k \rvert >\epsilon_n \} \right) = 0.
$$

By continuity from above,

$$
 \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{j,k \geq n}  \{ \lvert X_j-X_k \rvert >\epsilon_n \} \right) = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j,k\geq n}\left\{\lvert X_j-X_k\rvert>\epsilon_n\right\}\right),
$$

which proves your claim.

Comment: Ok, you are working with the limsup of sets. The only thing that is not clear to me is that thing with the sequence $(\varepsilon_n)$... is that enough to handle any $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: Yes, proving "for all $\epsilon > 0$..." is the same as proving "for all $\epsilon_n$...".

Comment: I cant imagine how the sequence $(\varepsilon_n)$ looks like. Are this positive real numbers from $>0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Take $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Isn't it continuity from below here?

Comment: Well, it's a decreasing sequence of sets.

Comment: Why decreasing and decreasing to what?

Comment: And I do not understand why showing it for all $\varepsilon > 0$ is the same as to show it for all $\varepsilon_n:=1/n$, because in the second case one shows it only for all $0<\varepsilon\leq 1$....

Comment: Could you pls answer my questions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12179/discussion-between-michael-and-math12)